# Unable to access jarfile when using xp_cmdshell

Tags: java, sql-server, t-sql, jar, xp-cmdshell

I have a jar file that I want to call/run from an *SQL stored procedure*. To do this, I am using **xp_cmdshell**.

I haven't created the stored procedure yet but, basically, the content of the stored procedure would be

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'java -jar D:\...\...\...\Test_LowerJDK.jar';
```

I am trying to run this line thru *SQL Server Management Studio*, just to see if it will work before I create the official stored procedure. However, when I run it, it gives me the following message.

> Unable to access jarfile D:.........\Test_LowerJDK.jar

I am not sure why this is happening. I'm guessing its because I wasn't able to go to the specific directory that I want to. If it is, how could I go to the specific directory that I want to so that I can run the jar file in that directory.

FYI
I tried running my jar file from the directory where it is saved thru command prompt by

```
java -jar Test_LowerJDK.jar
```

Also I tried opening a command prompt in C: and did the following

```
java -jar D:\...\...\...\Test_LowerJDK.jar
```

Both work just fine.

Also, I tried displaying my current working directory using **xp_cmdshell** using,

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'dir';
```

And it seems like my current working directory is

> Directory of C:\Windows\system32

I didn't want to paste my jar file in `C:\Windows\system32` 'cause I might mess things up? I'm  not sure that's why I didn't do it.

Comment: A few things to try: 1) Make sure permissions are OK for the DB user. 2) Ensure java is in the path for that user. 3) Try putting the filepath in double quotes e.g. EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'java -jar "D:\...\...\...\Test_LowerJDK.jar"' 4) Ensure that is the local path to the database server;

Comment: Also: only do one of those at a time! :) Sometimes you miss the actual solution if you go sledgehammer

Comment: Hi @Nick Pfitzner!
Thank you for this but for 1) I am actually using an Administrator user already. I previously used a different user and whenever I use xp_cmdshell, it would display a message that says I don't have permission. So no, I am already using an administrator account. For 2), I am not sure what you mean. But since the java version displays properly when I type `java -version` in the command prompt, I think this one is OK. For 3), I tried putting double quotes in the path but still it gives me the same message of "Unable to access jarfile"

Comment: @Nick Pfitzner, I was able to point out what's wrong. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why I was getting the following message.

> Unable to access jarfile D:......\TeamFolder\Test_LowerJDK.jar

The folder that contains Test_LowerJDK.jar is only accessible to a specific User Group. My Administrator account is not a part of the group that can access TeamFolder thus, it cannot access the jarfile.

I tried copying Test_LowerJDK.jar to C:\ and tried the following command.

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'java -jar C:\Test_LowerJDK.jar';
```

It worked well.

The reason I didn't immediately thought about this situation is because using Administrator account I can actually access and go to TeamFolder thru Windows Explorer. I forgot the fact that TeamFolder is actually a local folder in the machine where I logged in as Administrator that's why I can access TeamFolder neatly thru Windows Explorer.